# How to initialize 16 bit int in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a datalog parser for a robot controller, and what's coming in from the data log is a number in the range of 0 - 65535 (which is a 16 bit unsigned integer if I'm not mistaken). I'm trying to convert that to a signed 16 bit integer to display to the user (since that was the actual datatype before the logger changed it).

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a 16-bit integer?

Comment: Please show your code. If you have two bytes, you can use [`BitConverter.ToUint16`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.touint16?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Converting from unsigned quantities to signed "just works" in C#, though for safety's sake and to make your intent clear you could add `unchecked` (e.g. `short s = unchecked((short) 65535)` -- this is actually necessary when converting a constant, but optional otherwise).

Comment: Does 0 from the datalogger represent 0 or 32768? Or maybe some other number. What does 32768 from the datalogger represent? -1 or something else?

Comment: [Integral numeric types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) -> [UInt16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint16?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1):

Try using explicit casting.

Using unchecked here avoids a crash if [X] Check for Arithmetic Overflow is on:

```
    UInt16 x = 65535;
    Int16 y = unchecked((Int16)x);
```

Comment: It does not avoid a crash, but it avoids a `System.OverflowException`.  `Console.WriteLine($"{x} {y}");` returns `65535 -1` in your example;